# Import modules from a list or dict in Python?

Tags: python, import, nuke

Im fairly versed in Python, however this has been an issue for quite some time for me.

I have a folder full of scripts that the artists in my studio use within Nuke. In order for them to be accessible from within, I need to import them via and init.py file that Nuke reads on load.

I would like to be able to make a list of these values, either via a glob search to find everything applicable, or a declared list like:

```
my_list = ['mod_1', 'mod_2', 'mod_3']
```

Yet I have been unable to find a method that can handle this. I know I can use variable names to find the modules and import them via:

```
module = getattr(__import__(package, fromlist=[name]), name)
```

or

```
module = __import__(var)
```

but both of these methods require me to assign a name for the module I am importing.

I am looking for a way to do something along these lines:

```
capture = glob.glob('/scriptLocation/*.py')
for i in capture:
    import i
```

or

```
my_list = ['mod_1', 'mod_2', 'mod_3']
for i in capture:
    import i
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
modules = map(__import__, moduleNames)
```

Verify this [link for more](http://www.diveintopython.net/functional_programming/dynamic_import.html): (Example 16.15)

```
>>> moduleNames = ['sys', 'os', 're', 'unittest'] 1
>>> moduleNames
['sys', 'os', 're', 'unittest']
>>> modules = map(__import__, moduleNames)        2
>>> modules                                       3
[<module 'sys' (built-in)>,
<module 'os' from 'c:\Python22\lib\os.pyc'>,
<module 're' from 'c:\Python22\lib\re.pyc'>,
<module 'unittest' from 'c:\Python22\lib\unittest.pyc'>]
>>> modules[0].version                            4
'2.2.2 (#37, Nov 26 2002, 10:24:37) [MSC 32 bit (Intel)]'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'2.2.2 (#37, Nov 26 2002, 10:24:37) [MSC 32 bit (Intel)]'
```

Comment: Thanks! Setting it up the second I get back in the office! Cheers!

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you! The only issue is remembering which index is which module, but honestly, not a problem when compared to having to write 5 lines per import. Thanks again!

Comment: from the `__import__` doc : *Because this function is meant for use by the Python interpreter and not for general use it is better to use `importlib.import_module()` to programmatically import a module.*